# How does one save a form collection in key value pair

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a form with about 50 number fields html type and I need an Effiecent way of looping through them and save them in a table so i thought a simple keyvalue pair dictonary would suffice but of course asp.net only allows one form tag with run at server in it so my quesiton is how do i process the form fields in c#

I was going to use something like this but im sure in year 2016 there is a smatter way of doing a form value store.

```
    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringDictionary KeyValue = new StringDictionary();

        KeyValue.Add("", "");


        foreach (string key in Request.Form)
        {
            if (!key.StartsWith("checkbox")) continue;

        KeyValue.Add(key ,value)
        }


    }
```

Comment: This code miss how you get the `value`... The rest looks nice to save what you say... din't think anything better.

Comment: @Aristos that is what i do not no ideally i would want to store the id name of the textbox and also the value

Answer (score 0):

You can use CheckBoxList on asp.net WebForms
[CheckBoxList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: you did not read my entire comment this is nothing to do with checkboxes this is asking what is  best way of storing a form is it key value pair plz dont try to answer questions when only new its not doing you any favours

Comment: Ok, my answer is in no way. If you want to work with all html elements together. You should to create WebControl and work with them in here.

Comment: again not constructive and just a thow in the wind answer

Comment: try use linq var res = Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(x=>x.StartsWith("Check")).ToDictionary(x => x, x => Request.Form[x]); or Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(x=>x.StartsWith("Check")).Select(key=>new { Key =key, value= Request.Form[key]})

Answer (score 0):

You can loop all your controls inside your form and check what type that control is.

```
foreach (Control button in this.Controls)
{
     if (button.GetType() == typeof(Checkbox) )
     {
           // key value pair here   
     }
}
```